# Entering empty space enables the submit button in angular form how to trim and validate

Tags: angularjs, forms

I have a form, In this form I need to validate the password field. in my form field if I enter just a empty space the `submit` button getting enabled. so how to prevent this kind of scenario?

As well I would like to check the "re-enter" password field against my password field how can I compare both?

once both of them are correct I would like to enable the submit button. even I may required to restrict the user to enter min 6 character in the password field.

At present I am not getting any error at all.

her is my code :

```
<form name="myForm" novalidate ng-submit="myFormDetails(userInfo)">

      <label for="password">
        Enter Password
        <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="userInfo.password" id="password" required>
        <span class="error"  
          ng-show="myForm.password.$dirty && myform.password.$invalid">
            Please Provide Valid Password
          </span>
      </label>

      <label for="password">
        Re-Enter Password
        <input type="password" name="repassword" id="repassword" ng-model="userInfo.repassword" required>
        <span class="error" 
        ng-show="myForm.repassword.$dirty && myform.repassword.$invalid">
          Password not matching
      </span>
      </label>
      <label for="submit">
        <button type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
      </label>
    </form>
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/8z5PtueBhEcoMvRHrtWA?p=preview)

Comment: Typo: myform should be myForm, in multiple places

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ng-pattern to provide a regular expression that will exclude the spaces:

```
ng-pattern="/^[^\s]+$/"
```

Then add this to the ng-show to ensure the passwords are the same:

```
ng-show="myForm.repassword.$dirty &&
      (userInfo.password != userInfo.repassword || !myForm.repassword.$valid)"
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/cDbTN8x8bSl03NkpGWhO

Comment: I think if you add a `ng-minlength` it's a complete answer!

Comment: Also, no need to add the regex pattern check on the second password field, as it's compared to the main password field anyway

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add checks to your ng-disabled parameter. I personally prefer to work with functions within controllers, this makes the templates easier to read, because there should be as little logic in there as possible.

```
this.isInvalid = function() {
    var myForm = $scope.myForm;
    var valid = myForm.$valid;
    valid = valid && myForm.password.$modelValue.trim().length > 0;
    valid = valid && myForm.repassword.$modelValue.trim().length > 0;
    valid = valid && myForm.password.$modelValue.trim() === myForm.repassword.$modelValue.trim();

    return !valid;
};
```

I've forked your plunker into this:
http://plnkr.co/edit/qaWaXxnCi63uCS8oLyB1?p=preview